# What happens when a Levitating creature teleports higher into the air?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

For example, assume a spellcaster has cast [*levitate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/levitate) on themselves, and further casts [*dimension door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) to a point 500 feet straight up in the air.

Do they

- stay levitating at their new height?
- fall back to their previous height?
- something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The caster levitates at the new altitude

The [*Levitate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/levitate) spell does not limit the altitude a creature can levitate at. There is only one limit specified:

> One creature or object of your choice that you can see within range rises vertically [and] **must remain within the spell's range**.

The spell's range is measured from the caster, which is the thing being teleported. As a result, there is no conflict with being teleported to a higher altitude which would cause the *Levitate* spell to end or perform differently.

Further, as *Dimension Door* does not require concentration, it does not break concentration for *Levitate*. The end result is that the caster, already levitating, would teleport to a new altitude and continue to levitate there until the spell ended (or was caused to end by some other means).

Comment: This is a great way to 'climb' a cliff :)